# Посоветуйте KVM IP Switch

Tags: kvm-switch

Есть ПК под управлением MAC OS 9 (раритет еще тот), нужно им удаленно управлять. Какой KVM IP Switch можете посоветовать под эту задачу?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Могу посоветовать [ATEN](http://www.aten.ru/support/artview.php?idx=366)сами пользуемся

Answer (score 0):

собственно какая ос - не так важно. какой компьютер?   если с белыми яблоками - то любой KVM с USB хвостиками. а если с цветным яблоком, то гемор - у мышки и клавы свои разъемы :(